# Hide url on mouseover php short-url?

Tags: php, hyperlink, short-url

I have a script that acts as a short url I would like to hide when I hover over the url, I am attaching the code:

```
<div class="container splash">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">

                            <a href="<?php echo $url->url ?>" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block redirect" rel="nofollow"><?php echo e("GO GO GO CONTINUE"); ?></a>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I also attach a screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yzMZ.png
I'm not that good at programming so I ask for a hand kindly

Comment: What you see is browser behavioral. As developer of application you cannot change it. All browsers show url when hover over anchor tag for security reasons. User should be able to see where he/she is clicking.

Comment: I read around that it is possible to hide it.
it would not be to damage security because then they see which link it leads to ...